# Vendor wants me to make Exchange 2013 EWS Redirect Like Exchange 2010. Is this a bad idea?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2013

I have vendor who provides us "Secure" email on our phones. The service uses the EWS\exchange.asmx to run the service and on Exchange 2010 this page automatically redirects to EWS\Services.wsdl.

We recently upgraded to 2013 and this behavior changed. Instead of autoredirecting to EWS\Services.wsdl when you go to EWS\Exchange.asmx it brings you to a Service Status Page like so.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztViq.jpg

If you goto EWS\Services.wsdl manually on 2013, everything works as expected.
This vendor refuses to accept this new behavior and says we must make 2013 EWS\Exchange.asmx to automatically redirect to EWS\Services.wsdl.
When I explained that this was expected behavior they told me I need to figure out how to make Exchange 2013 automattically redirect the EWS\Exchange.asmx page to EWS\Services.wsdl on Exchange 2013.

I guess my questions are.

1. Is it safe to put a redirect in for EWS\Exchange.asmx?
2. How to I properly redirect that page without breaking things?
3. Should I tell the vendor they are doing things wrong and they need to figure out their software?

My last conversation with them, they told me that I needed to call Microsoft to have them help me reconfigure EWS as they do not know the needed changes.

Here is there official response.

> Unfortunately we are unable to do that. Our ZixOne server is set to
>   got to the /ews/exchange.asmx page for all our ZixOne customers. You
>   will need to find out why it brings you to the service page, and I
>   believe Microsoft would be better able to help you with that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn´t do any "redirection" as EWS is also use by Microsoft Office for MAC and you might break that or at least cause issues.

But you might add additional IPs (or one IP if no cluster) to your Exchange server and then add an additional EWS virtual directory (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125176(v=exchg.160).aspx)). You can then put an redirect here and use the non standard/default EWS directory for the implementation with there software.

*Offtopic: I personally would also drop that vendor and move to another one. There are a lot of other container solutions if needed which offer much better support (e.g. VMWare AirWatch). I personally never pick a vendor which copyright on there own website is outdated and showed an old date (like with your one). If they do not take care of such simple and easy stuff like that, they might also fail in so many other sections.*